# How to save an image in a private directory in Laravel and then give it to be displayed in the browser?

Tags: laravel

I want to save images to a special directory, example - storage/private_files And show certain images to certain users after authorization. The user’s images will then have to be displayed in the IMG tag in the browser. Paths to files will be stored in the database in conjunction with the user. How to properly organize saving and serving images in Laravel 8.83.21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a plenty of way to do it (middleware, policies, user_permissions, ...).

What I would suggest *(I don't know what your model calls or the structure of your code, but when you get the idea apply it on yours)*:

- Add new disk in `config/filesystems.php`

```php
'disks' => [
    'private' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/private_files'),
        'visibility' => 'private',
        'throw' => true,
    ],
],
```

- To Save your file:

`$file->storeAs("uploads", "image_x.jpg", "private");` Or using [Storage Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#main-content)

- If file is downloadable for certain user (using Policies)

Example of working with [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies)

```php
class FilePolicy
{
    public function download(User $user, FileModel $file): bool
    {
        return $user->isAdmin();
        //OR
        return $user->hasAccessTo($file); // assuming you have that function  

    }

    public function show(User $user, FileModel $file): bool
    {
        return $user->isAdmin();
        //OR
        return $user->hasAccessTo($file); // assuming you have that function  

    }
}
```

```php
// XController.php

public function download(FileModel $file): void
 {
    if ($request->user()->cannot('download', FileModel)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return Storage::response($file->filename);
}
```

- In your [view blade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-blade-templates)

```php
@can('show', $file) // similar for download
    <!-- The current user can see the file... -->
@endcan
```

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using the temporary url function. If the user has access, you can create a temporary url for him and give the user access. And since the temporary url is expired, it cannot share the url with other users. This is the best way to handle file permissions:

```
$url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
    'file.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

Comment: "_This is the best way to handle file permissions_" Is it really? Does it even have anything to do with file permissions? "_it cannot share the url with other users_" What? Why? The URL _can_ be shared as long as it is available